Did Poland plant forests near the post-war German border for military protection?
Are the following statements correct, and are there any quality sources to confirm?

East of rivers Oder and Neisse, there are huge forests.
Covering ground that was agricultural land before WW II.
After the German population was driven out, villages in this zone were never repopulated.
The forests were planted on purpose, as a defense line against tanks.
Because for a long while after the war, Polish government and society feared that Germany sooner or later would try to reconquer lost territories.


A tempting proposition, no doubt. And if you look at the land coverage east of the Oder, there are in fact large forested areas. But all of them coincide with the eastern border of the river lowlands (Oderbruch), and start atop of hills and ridges. Surely higher ground is a better protection than trees? – Yes, the western ridge of the river is much steeper, but the eastern side also has 20-30 meters with the exeption of the Warthe valley, and that is swampy, not forrested.

Source?  Citation? Research?

Forests do stop tanks but they make excellent cover for infantry pushes, as seen in the Korean and Vietnam wars most recently. So I doubt this would be the case.

This thesis has no ground to stand on. Military use of land was determined by the Soviet Red Army and the Warsaw Pact, not by Polish nationalist feelings, which had no place in the official policy where Poland and Eastern Germany were "brother countries".
If you look at land use before the war, and in the 1970s, you will see a reduction of agriculture. But this happened only after 1950, when the former arable land had already been redistributed to new owners. Only later mechanization and industrialization resulted in giving up marginal land.
And there are indeed areas where military used the forest, but not by planting trees.
Elżbieta Bielecka, Andrzej Ciołkosz: Land use changes during the 19th and 20th century. The case of the Odra River catchment area, Geographia Polonica (2002) vol. 75, iss. 1, pp. 67-83 has investigated the matter¹:

In 1946, about 1.5 million German citizens were repatriated to Germany. The native population only remained in place in larger numbers in the Opole region. Polish repatriates from the USSR and Czechoslovakia slowly settled the area. The new settlers were given land parcels, of 10 ha on average and not exceeding 50 ha. Most of the agricultural land was organised into large state farms. The agricultural ownership structure from the Silesian Lowland up to the northern reaches of the Odra Basin is very well reflected on satellite images: a mosaic of very small peasant fields plus the large fields of the state farms...
Analysis of land use information obtained from historical maps and satellite
images taken in 1975 show that land use changes in this period were minimal.
The most important changes that are to be noted for the last hundred years are
those concerning forests, which increased in area by more than 3000 km² (4.9% of the basin area). Contributory factors in this were above all the country's policy on agriculture, whose aim was to withdraw marginal soils from agricultural production. The result was the reforestation of the weakest soils least suited to agriculture. Unfortunately, the increase in the area of forests was accompanied by deterioration in their quality. This was linked post 1945 with the stationing of Soviet troops within the forests, and the resultant conversion of considerable areas into military bases and training grounds. The largest such areas were to be found in Bory Dolnośląskie. A second cause of the worsening in the condition of forest was of course air pollution and resultant acid rain...
The loss of agricultural land within the Odra basin can be observed from the end of WW2 onwards. Fallows accounted for more than 60% of arable land in 1946 and an increase in the latter's share back to the levels noted pre 1938 was only achieved at the beginning of the 1950s. The subsequent 25 years to 1975 saw a slow decline in the area of arable land with a simultaneous increase in the area of meadows, pastures, woods and built-up areas. The decline was very much a reflection of the assumptions underpinning state and co-operative agriculture, which reduced the profitability of cereal-growing while raising that of cattle- and pig-rearing.

First the Germans were expulsed, then the agricultural lands were distributed mainly to state farms and additionally to small landowners. Then marginal soils were decommisioned and reforested because of low productivity.
Independent of that, the Soviet army (which was also on the German side of the border) was stationed in forests (new and old) in the area. But that lead to its detoriation, and actually since the 1980s, in conjunction with the catastrophic air polution and acid rain, the forests started to die.

¹ For some reason, the Warthe valley was not part of the study, which makes a strange definition of "catchment area", since the Warthe is a Oder tributary.
